# how to draw route in gmap having latitude and longitude updating in real time (once per second)

Tags: c#, gps, gmap.net

I would like to draw the real time position of an object using as input values the data that I receive in real time with a serial port. I recive 2 data: Latitude and Longitude. I'm trying to do it using gMap.net but I'm only able to set a list of pre-registered points and then create the route.. But it isn't what i have to do.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You create your GMaps Route at the beginning, then add it to an overlay. (It sounds like that's what you've done already.)

You can then retrieve that same route from the overlay you added it to, usually using the name that you assigned to it at the beginning. You can then update the route with your new data, as often as you like.